# I disconnected my wireless headset, now I am trying to find it again

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, peripherals, wireless-headset

System: Windows 10
Peripheral: Beats Solo 3

I had to hard reset my beats and disconnected them from my computer in an attempt to help my phone discover them again. (which worked) Now my computer doesn't find the beats in my "Manage Bluetooth devices" menu. I have rebooted the computer and the beats and still cannot find them. I *assumed* they would return in the "ready to pair" state. Any advice or feedback would be appreciated, as I am already feeling dumb.

Answer (score -2):

You may have to turn on the active search on your headset again. There should be a button on your headset to "pair to device" or something along those lines. Open your Manage Bluetooth devices on your computer then hit that button.